# Checking connections to RavenDB

Tags: networking, ravendb, ravendb-studio, nosql

I have following problem:

I'm using `RavenDB` I have configured Indexes at the database. After a while definition of indexes has been changed in code. All is running well at my machine, but as soon as I push changes to production, modified indexes are constantly reset to previous definition.

I know that this is because of connection with "old" version of code to same database.

Is there any way to check at RavenDb (possibly at Studio) where those connections are coming from?

Temporarily I just locked indexes at db, but this is not solution of the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.